# React router only working with Link to, not with URL or on refresh

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Not sure what is happening here. I have set up my routing and when I go to my first page localhost:8080/ the first route renders as expected. However if I enter into the url in localhost:8080/store the expected route fails and I receive a 404 cannot find (doesnt even fallback to my not found component).

However if I set up a Link to and click the link it will render my store route as expected.

Shouldn't `/store` render out my StorePicker component regardless if its entered into the URL or selected via a Link to element?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

//Components
import StorePicker from './components/StorePicker.js';
import Main from './components/Main';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Link to="/store">Store</Link>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={StorePicker} />
                    <Route path="/store" component={Main} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </div>

        </Router>
    )
}

render(<Routes />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? If yes, How?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Webpack. If so, adding a few things to your webpack config should solve the issue. Specifically, `output.publicPath = '/'` and `devServer.historyApiFallback = true`.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```